# windowsphone 8:How To Avoid White Blank Screen Splashing a Second Before Loading WebBrowser

Tags: windows-phone-8

I just want to resolve the issue that when i'm loading the content of html in a webview a white blank screen splashing on webview.Is it browser default background color?or the behaviour like this? is there any solution for this issue.Please any one help how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to make it visible after the navigation was completed. See here for more info:
[Windows Phone WebBrowser control tips](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/09/17/windows-phone-webbrowser-control-tips/)

Comment: One more doubt how to set same thing when i'm adding html pages to the WebBrowser using pivot?

Comment: Can you explain it bit more? How do use Pivot to assign webpages to WebBrowser?

Comment: In XAML i'm creating one pivot inside that binding html to web browser as pivot item. When it is loading for first time only first page of the web browser flashing a second with white screen.for this is there any solution?

Comment: You can handle the Navigating event of a WebBrowser. For example you can hide the browser control when user starts navigation, show progressring, wait for navigated event and then make the control visible.